# Code understanding issue in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am not understanding what is happening in the following code.Can someone please explain me what is happening with this code?

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>

<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="2; URL=UploadFile.do">

<base href="UploadFile.do">

<title>SOI File Upload</title>

<BODY>

<% 
request.getSession().setAttribute(Constants.FROM_TRANSLATE_PAGE, "Y"); 

%>

<H3 align="center">Loading...</H3>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: What are you not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dark Knights answer a bit.

The code displays a page with a title and a text saying Loading...

In the background it sets a session attribute (as Dark Knight described) for the attribute name within `Constants.FROM_TRANSLATE_PAGE` to the value `"Y"`.

Finally after two seconds it will ask the browser to refresh the page and redirect it to `UploadFile.do`. That is what this line does: `<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="2; URL=UploadFile.do">`

The `base href` sets a default URL (and target if present) for the page but does not have much effect unless there are any links on the page.

Ref:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Answer (score 0):

The only logic i can see here is,  on load of this page value "Y" is set in session scope for attribute as `Constants.FROM_TRANSLATE_PAGE`

Comment: does it do any other progress ? like redirecting or something else>?

Comment: Yes, it will request the browser to do a redirect to the page UploadFile.do